# replacing an image in canvs - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm attempting to make a very simple meme generator, whereby you select the image you want to add text onto using a drop down menu. I can successfully select the image I want and display it within the canvas, however when I change my selection, instead of changing the image it adds it over the first image.

I'd like to be able to chose the image, and if i change my mind it simply replaces the current image. Any suggestions you might have would be very welcome!

Here's my code:

```
window.onload = function init(){

var selector = document.getElementById('selector');    
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageObj = new Image();
var imagesObj = {
    "fry"       :   ['images/fry.jpg'],
    "badluck"   :   ['images/badluck.jpg'],
    "success"   :   ['images/success.jpg']

};


selector.addEventListener('change', function(){
    imagesObj[selector.value].forEach(function(item){
    imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
    };
    imageObj.src = item;


});
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this did the trick:

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, 298, 350);
```